# Htaccess :Rewrite rule issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've following code in a .htaccess file. The file is in a subfolder, lets say /content/.

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?(/(edit)+)(/([^/]+))?/?$ edit.php?category=$1&slug=$3&edit=$5&password=$7 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+)?/?)$ content.php?category=$1&slug=$3 [L]
```

I'm expecting above code will rewrite,

1. mydomain.com/content/text1/text2/edit/my_password   to mydomain.com/content/edit.php?category=text1&slug=text2&password=my_password
2. mydomain.com/content/text1/text2   to mydomain.com/content/content.php?category=text1&slug=text2
3. mydomain.com/content/text1 to mydomain.com/content/content.php?category=text1
4. mydomain.com/content/   to mydomain.com/content/content.php

The code rewrites above correctly, But it breaks the asset urls.
e.g. It rewrites http://mydomain.com/content/js/tms.js to something else, it is same for the css files. My assets folders are /img, /css, /js.

If i commented          `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?(/(edit)+)(/([^/]+))?/?$ edit.php?category=$1&slug=$3&edit=$5&password=$7 [L]`  line it works for the assets

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is `/content/text1/text2/edit/my_password` an actual file or directory? Your conditions check if the URI is a file/directory that exists.

Comment: @Jon "content" is a folder on root. others are not..

Comment: If the others aren't real directories, I don't understand how the first rule can work when the conditions placed on it is the request (e.g. `/content/text1/text2/edit/my_password`) **must** be an existing symlink, an existing file, or an existing directory. The second rule has no conditions on it at all so I can at least see that one working

Comment: @JonLin I wanted to apply the rule if there is no such file exists. Is the condition wrong for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` means that "the request is for an existing directory". If you add a `!` in front of the `-d` it changes it to "the request is not for an existing directory".

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/edit)+/([^/]+?)/?$ edit.php?category=$1&slug=$2&password=$4 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+?)/?$ content.php?category=$1&slug=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)/?$ content.php?category=$1 [L]
```